# Swift, facebook login & firebase auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }


    /*
    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        /*
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }
        // User is signed in
        // ...
        print("Login facebook ok")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         */
    }
     */
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch {
        print ("Logout fel")
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var epostTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var forgotPassword: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var registrera: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loggaIn: UIButton!

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == epostTextField{
        passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    }else{
        passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(loginButton)

    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 300, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)

    self.epostTextField.delegate = self
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyBoard))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    epostTextField.font = UIFont(name:"BebasNeue", size: 20)
    passwordTextField.font = UIFont(name:"BebasNeue", size: 20)
    forgotPassword.titleLabel?.font = UIFont (name: "BebasNeue", size: 20)
    registrera.titleLabel?.font = UIFont (name: "BebasNeue", size: 20)
    loggaIn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont (name: "BebasNeue", size: 20)

}


@objc func hideKeyBoard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil){
    view.endEditing(true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func loggaIn(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: epostTextField.text!, password:
    passwordTextField.text!){


        (user, error) in

        if(error != nil)
        {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Fel vid inloggning", message: "Felaktig e-post eller lösenord", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


            print("Fel vid Login")
        } else {
            print("Login ok")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }


}

@IBAction func registrera(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: epostTextField.text!, password:
    passwordTextField.text!) {
        (user, error) in

        if(error != nil)
        {

            print("Fel vid registrering")
        } else {
            print("Registrering ok")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}


@IBAction func forgotPassword(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Nytt lösenord skickat", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
`Im using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.
```

So I have done all the steps in Facebook developer and followed firebase steps also.

[My login viewController image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odF8m.png)

So right now, in the code above, I get transferred to Facebook, and can sign in, but when I get back to the app, I'm still in the loginviewcontroller and I'm not being sent to the next viewController. If I try to uncomment the code in the pic above, everything crashes when I'm trying to get back to the app after Facebook login. And thats when I get this error message.

> 2017-10-31 16:02:49.768994+0100 Wishes[1479:446286] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x1c42203c0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x182047d38 0x18155c528 0x1820551f8 0x18204d6e4 0x181f330dc 0x100568b58 0x100563910 0x100562768
>   0x100561860 0x10054dab4 0x10054d728 0x10054d47c 0x101be149c
>   0x101be145c 0x101bf0110 0x101be49a4 0x101bf1104 0x101bf8100
>   0x181c72fe0 0x181c72c30) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

**I need som serious help, I'm studying app development atm, and my teacher couldn't even figure it out**

Comment: would you post your code instant image

Comment: whats inside your viewDidLoad()? Post your whole VC code(NOT in an image)

Comment: I added the code for the whole view controller. I also have a "regular" signup option further down if you see code like *signin* *signout* *register*

Comment: @EllinorHeimer did you set set the **other linker Flag**?

Comment: yes but it still didn't work

Comment: @EllinorHeimer what is error now? if same error then you did not setup  the **other linker Flag** proper way